# how to add activity through favourite button

Tags: android, android-studio, math, favorites

i am currently working on a maths application.I want to add a favourite button through which the user can add it to the favourite list.Till now i have added the favourite button but how to add the activity to the favourites when a user clicks it.can anybody tell me???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to create a list of the user's favorite Activities in a String list? To do this...

1. get the name of the Activity using `String mActivityName = this.getClass().getSimpleName();`
2. create an ArrayList using `ArrayList mFavList;` which will collect the Activity names.
3. Set an OnClickListener on the button which will add the Activity name to the ArrayList `mFavList.add(mActivityName)`

Comment: But how can i access those activity, i cant just simply by name stored in my ArrayList ?